# How to transform/convert likelihoods to scores?

Tags: distributions, likelihood, transform, credit-scoring

I have the probability of loan default for a labeled dataset where the distribution of probabilities is heavily skewed. Labels are defined as "good/0" for no default and "bad/1" for defaults. My goal is to transform the distribution of probabilities to a score, ranged between 1-100 such that at subsequent intervals of custom length, the bad rate decreases equally.

e.g. for interval of length = 10 ->

[1-10) holds 50% of bads
[10-20) holds 25% of bads
.
.
.

Is there any method to do to such transformation?

[image: distribution of probabilities]